# Wrapping p- and ul-elements in the same container

Tags: jquery

I need to wrap all p and ul-Elements with a div-container (class=editable) via JQuery. All elements in the same "content"-Container should be wrapped in the same editable-container.

So this HTML-Code...

```
<div id="article">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <section class="box_1">
        <header class="trigger"><h2>Title</h2></header>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem</li>
                <li>ipsum</li>
            </ul>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="box_1">
        <header class="trigger"><h2>Title</h2></header>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

...should become this...

```
<div id="article">
    <div class="editable">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <section class="box_1">
        <header class="trigger"><h2>Title</h2></header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="editable"> <!-- this part doesn't work right now -->
                <ul>
                    <li>Lorem</li>
                    <li>ipsum</li>
                </ul>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div> <!-- this part doesn't work right now -->
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="box_1">
        <header class="trigger"><h2>Title</h2></header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="editable">
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

I'm using this code:

```
$('.content > p, #article > p').each(function () {
    if (!$(this).closest('.editable').length) $(this).nextUntil('div, section').addBack().wrapAll("<div class='editable' />");
});
```

...and this works fine for every p-element. But how do I have to modify that, so the ul-Elements (with the inner li-Elements) are handled like a p-element? They should also be wrapped.

Comment: Is there something preventing you from adding the editable class to the content divs rather than creating new nested divs? (i.e. `<div class="content editable">`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate through the elements and wrap their `p` and `ul` children:

```
$('#article, .content').each(function() {
    $(this).children('p, ul').wrapAll("<div class='editable' />");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Le9r/