# Wrapping p- and ul-elements

Tags: jquery

I need to wrap all p- and ul-elements with a div-container in the following way:

```
$('.content> p, #article> p').each(function () {
    if (!$(this).closest('.editable').length) $(this).nextUntil('div, section').addBack().wrapAll("<div class='editable' />");
});
```

In this code just the p-elements are wrapped. How do I have to change the code to wrap p- and ul-elements. Both should be treated in the same way.

```
<p>Test</p>
<ul><li>Test</li></ul>
<p>Test</p>
```

In this case all three elements should be wrapped to:

```
<div class="editable">
    <p>Test</p>
    <ul><li>Test</li></ul>
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

**Update**: This could be an example content:

```
<div id="article">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <section class="box_1">
        <header class="trigger"><h2>Title</h2></header>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem</li>
                <li>ipsum</li>
            </ul>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="box_1">
        <header class="trigger"><h2>Title</h2></header>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

I first tried this answer [Wrapping p- and ul-elements in the same container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640486/wrapping-p-and-ul-elements-in-the-same-container/24640726#24640726).
But it need the part `$(this).nextUntil('div, section').addBack().wrapAll("<div class='editable' />")`

So, would be this correct or could I make that (`$('.content> p, #article> p, .content> ul, #article> ul')`) a little bit easier?

```
$('.content> p, #article> p, .content> ul, #article> ul').each(function () {
    if (!$(this).closest('.editable').length) $(this).nextUntil('div, section').addBack().wrapAll("<div class='editable' />");
});
```

Comment: are there only these 2 `p` tags and the one `ul` tag in your code?

Comment: This is the third time that I see you are asking this question. What was wrong with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640486/wrapping-p-and-ul-elements-in-the-same-container/24640726#24640726)?

Comment: First I thought it worked. But it messed up the result. The script is part of an editor. The user can select some text and format it. After this the above script should put the editable-elements. But this doesn't work in a proper way. So I need the part `$(this).nextUntil('div, section').addBack().wrapAll("<div class='editable' />")` - which isn't in the linked aswer...

Comment: Then you should un-accept the answer you accepted and edit the original question -- don't keep reposting the same question.

Comment: Ok, sorry with that. But I thought, that the answer was correct for that question. I didn't explain the special case with my editor. So i think it would not be correct to un-accept a correct answer to the given question.

Answer (score -2):

Like this?

```
$('p, ul').each(function () {
    if (!$(this).closest('.editable').length) $(this).wrapAll("<div class='editable' />");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jY7UW/

Comment: It doesn't work based on the last example the OP posted.